# How to ignore required options when --help flag is used

Tags: node.js, command-line-interface, node-commander

In my code, I have a required option:

```js
Program.requiredOption('-r, --remote <url>', 'specifies the root url')
```

When I specify `--help` or `-h` or use the subcommand `help`, I get this `error: required option '-r, --remote <url>' not specified`. The only way to view the help page is to just use the command without any flags or subcommands. e.g.

```sh
$ mycli #Shows help page
$ mycli --help #Error
$ mycli -h #Error
$ mycli help #Error
```

How can I make it so that when the `--help` flag or `help` subcommand is specified, Commander ignores the `requiredOption`?

Comment: Place the help command as first option? How does your code look like?

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Commander v4.0.0? That issue was fixed in v4.0.1.

https://github.com/tj/commander.js/releases/tag/4.0.1